# Pruning for multi-layer perceptron

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, mlp

Here, I have the single hidden layer multi-layer perceptron (Input: 4 units, hidden unit: 3 units, output: 1 unit).

I want to do pruning before a training process with Keras.
Concretely, I just want to remove the connection between the input units and hidden units. (so I don't remove the hidden units.)

Would you tell me how to implement this code?
Now I am thinking that the skip connection with merge and concat is one of the solution, however, it is not smart way when the number of the units and layers are increased.

Comment: How can you have skip connections in such a shallow net? Plus it's more popular in CNN based archs as well. (You can add dropouts and checkout other variants on it as well)